# Jump to date/ column heading

Tags: excel, vba

Some time ago I wrote a procedure which jumped to the respective line when pressing a button (Jan, Feb, Mar ..).
This was always applied to one area.
Now I would have to apply the same to to the headings of the columns.
The headings have the format "01.01.2018".

How to adapt the code now?
does anyone have an idea?

greeting

```
Sub PrcCurrentMonth()

Dim vNumber As Long
Dim vDate As Date
Dim vMonth As Variant
Dim vRange As Range

On Error GoTo ExitSub

vMonth = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).DrawingObject.Caption
vNumber = WorksheetFunction.Match(vMonth, Application.GetCustomListContents(7), 0)
vDate = DateSerial(2018, vNumber, 1)


Set vRange = ActiveSheet.Range("D4:ABK4").Find(vDate, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not vRange Is Nothing Then
        Application.GoTo vRange, True
        Set vRange = Nothing

    End If

ExitSub:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just this was necessary:

```
Set vRange = Range("TblOne[[#Headers],[" & vDate & "]]")
```